# Stop Galaxy S7 upgrade nag screen

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s7

Once or twice a day, I get a full screen nag from the OS asking me to upgrade to Android 7.  My phone is working great, so I'm not interested in upgrading as that will likely break and/or change things in ways I'd rather not deal with.

So, how do I prevent the nag screen from appear?  Preferably without rooting the phone.

Model: SM-G930U
Android version: 6.0.1
Android security path level: March 1st, 2017

Nag Screen:

[image]

Comment: I believe you can not. These updates are push over the air from the vendor. You can keep clicking on "LATER" if you manage

Comment: By vendor do you mean Samsung or the service provider Republic Wireless?
 That is what my service provider said.  I gave them a polite lecture on respecting customers.

Answer (score 1):

If the notification is really annoying you, you could get rid of it by performing the suggested method of disabling the process responsible for handling  system updates and associated activities named `com.wssyncmldm`.

Head to Google Play store and grab [Package Disabler Pro (Samsung)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ospolice.packagedisablerpro&hl=en)($1.49 not sure if there is free version, but reviews claim this is worth the bucs)

Open Package Disabler Pro and disable the process/service named  `com.wssyncmldm` and `com.sec.android.soagent`
 . This should stop the update notification.

*Disclaimer: I am no way associated with the app, and this is just for educational purposes, Information is gathered through research from credible sources.*

**Edit**: Package Disabler Pro 6.3 is recommended, read more here: https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyNote7/comments/5bnlcj/i_dont_think_so_verizon/

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to disable any package by using the `adb pm uninstall` command.
Note that this will not actually uninstall the app, but will only hide it from the system.  Best of all it works on non-rooted devices too!!
Enter this from your adb folder:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.wssyncmldm
```

If you really want to get rid of a lot of Security+OTA nagging, then run the following list of commands.  Optionally you can save it in a batch file to make it easier to run.  Note: Some packages will fail to uninstall which is fine, since this is a generic uninstall list for various Samsung models.

```
:Samsung Security+OTA Disabler (BillA 2017-01-01)  
:  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.sharedstoragebackup  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.carrieriq.tmobile  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.carrieriq.tmobile.IQOOB  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.carrieriq.tmobile.IQToggle  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.LocalFota  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.policydm  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.android.mdm  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.android.securitylogagent  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.sdm  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.sprint.chameleon  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.syncmlservice  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.diagmonagent  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.fotaclient  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.fwupgrade  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.soagent  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.omadmspr  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.omadmspr.syncmlphoneif  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sprint.zone  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sprint.w.installer  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.tmobile.pr.adapt  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.ws.dm  
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.wssyncmldm
```