# What is SOAgent in Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: applications

What is SOAgent in Samsung Galaxy,  and why it can connect to internet by itself?

How to Block SOAgent from Accessing the Internet ?

(and also it can't be disabled, SOAgent is very suspicious app)

Answer (score 1):

SOAgent (package name `com.sec.android.soagent`), is a system application or rather manufacturers tool that comes preloaded in most Samsung devices.

It is one of the packages responsible for checking software/security OTA updates, readying, alerting the user  and downloading such updates. As a system application it does have such privileges to access the internet to check for updates regularly to the annoyance of many users (not really necessary to sending alerts to download) because sometimes one may not be ready to install new updates.

One can remove (if rooted) or [disable this package](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176739/209414) if not rooted.

Android already has mechanisms to do such checks, since other devices receive updates without the presence of such an application or even doing offline updates will be great news for some.